# Cleanly create new column of categorical data

Tags: pandas, categorical-data

I can add a categorical column to a Pandas DataFrame like so:

```py
import pandas as pd

label_type = pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(categories=["positive", "negative"], ordered=False)

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# Create a new column, setting the value universally to "positive"
df['label'] = pd.Series(["positive"] * len(df), dtype=label_type).values
```

This is less elegant than this shorthand with other types:

```py
df['label2'] = "positive"  # sets entire column to str("positive")
```

but it seems like the underlying type is just a `str`

```py
print(type(df['label'].iloc[0]))
<class 'str'>
```

so it seems like the column-type has to be known ahead of time to pandas.

Is there any way to add a categorical column to a dataframe without manually constructing the `Series`?  For example,

```py
df['label3'] = label_type("positive")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
df['col4'] = df.assign(col4 = 'positive')['col4'].astype(label_type)

df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype   
---  ------  --------------  -----   
 0   col1    2 non-null      int64   
 1   col2    2 non-null      int64   
 2   label   2 non-null      category
 3   col4    2 non-null      category
dtypes: category(2), int64(2)
memory usage: 412.0 bytes
```

Though you still get an `str type`:

```
type(df['col4'].iloc[0])

str
```

Since I think that in this case `iloc[]` will return a string representation of the category.

Or just do it in two steps:

```
df['col4'] = 'positive'
df['col4'] = df['col4'].astype(label_type)
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! I think option 1 is closest to what I was looking for since it's a one-liner.